# Apply range on the values of redis cache

Tags: java, redis

I am using `Elastic cache` and `redis` in my project. I have the cache where `key` is `String` and `Employee` object as `value`. `Employee` class is as below. Is there any way to `query redis` such that it returns `employee` whose `startrange` and `endrange` fulfill the criteria : `startrange<input<endrange.` Where `input` will be passed to the query.

**Employee**

```
int startRange;
int endRange;
```

**Redis Entries**

```
1   Employee{startRange=12300 ,endRange=12399 }
2   Employee{startRange=45600 ,endRange=45699 }
3   Employee{startRange=78900 ,endRange=78999 }
```

**Input**: 12345

**Output**

```
1   Employee{startRange=12300 ,endRange=12399 }
```

Comment: The short answer is, "no." Redis is a key/value store with lots of advantages for specific situations, but value querying is not one of them.

Comment: You've already posted a similar question. Check the comment I made, and use a sorted set.